# ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence when trying to plot with matplotlib

Tags: python, arrays, matplotlib, sequence, valueerror

When I was trying to run the following code:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

Xpos = df[df['bound']==1]
Xneg = df[df['bound']==0]
y1, X1 = Xpos['Id'].values, Xpos['seq'].values
y2, X2 = Xneg['Id'].values, Xneg['seq'].values

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(y1, X1 , label='bounded sequences', color='blue')
ax.plot(y2, X2 , label='unbounded sequences', color='red')
plt.show()
```

I got this error:`ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.`
The sample output of `df` is like the one you find [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hS3Tq.png).
Can anyone help?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the issue here is that you are trying to plot a list of lists.

For the purpose of explaining you the issue, I created a sample dataset similar to the one you are using (the only difference is that the sequences are shorter). Here is the code that I'm using to create the dataset:

```
df_dict = {
    "Id": [0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
    "seq": [[0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0]],
    "bound": [1, 0, 1, 0, 1]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(df_dict)
```

If we now execute the first part of your code and print the X1 variable:

```
Xpos = df[df['bound']==1]
Xneg = df[df['bound']==0]
y1, X1 = Xpos['Id'].values, Xpos['seq'].values
y2, X2 = Xneg['Id'].values, Xneg['seq'].values
print(X1)
```

The output will be:

```
[list([0, 0, 1, 0]) list([0, 0, 1, 0]) list([0, 0, 1, 0])]
```

If what you would like to plot for X1 is the concatenation of each list, e.g. [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0], this might solve your problem:

```
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

df_dict = {
    "Id": [0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
    "seq": [[0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0]],
    "bound": [1, 0, 1, 0, 1]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(df_dict)

Xpos = df[df['bound']==1]
Xneg = df[df['bound']==0]
print(Xpos)
y1, X1 = Xpos['Id'].values, [elem for sub_list in Xpos['seq'].values for elem in sub_list]
y2, X2 = Xneg['Id'].values, [elem for sub_list in Xneg['seq'].values for elem in sub_list]
print(y1)
print(X1)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(X1, label='bounded sequences', color='blue')
ax.plot(X2, label='unbounded sequences', color='red')
plt.show()
```

If you want a scatter plot instead of a line plot, you just need to replace the two ax.plot functions with the following:

```
ax.scatter(range(len(X1)), X1, label='bounded sequences', color='blue')
ax.scatter(range(len(X2)), X2, label='unbounded sequences', color='red')
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. What I want to do is to plot X1 and X2 which are equivalent to the bounded sequences (df[df['bound']==1]) and the unbounded sequences ( df[df['bound']==0]) respectively.

Comment: In this case for example, X1 is [list([0, 0, 1, 0]) list([0, 0, 1, 0]) list([0, 0, 1, 0])] as shown above. Just to clarify, the values that you would like to plot for X1 should be the concatenation of each list, e,g, [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]?

Comment: Exactly, and I have already tried that with [int(j) for i in X1 for j in i] but I don't know where the error is?

Comment: I have edited the answer in order to include a possible solution for this issue, please let me know if this is what you were looking for.

Comment: works fine, but what I want  is a scatter plot of bounded and unbounded sequences instead. Thanks.

Comment: I added the option to add the scatter plot in the answer. If this solves your issue, please consider to mark my answer as accepted, thank you.